# Is this correct? : "Tenji that was, died in his sisters arms." (Kind of like 'powers that be') Also is 'have a claim to' correct' or 'hold a claim to'

Tags: grammaticality, expressions, word-usage

Full quote for context
"I have no claim to life, yet I walk. I have no claim to valor, yet I fight. I have no claim to love, yet I mourn. I am not the dragon, for Tenji Minamoto that was, died in his sister’s arms, choking on his own blood. I am the ghost in the armour, I am the sand in the sheath, I am just a shadow, but a shadow of the dragon nonetheless."

(Eng is not my first lang. So please go easy on me and forgive me if it's cheesy. I am doing a school project)

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it's fine. It is poetic, (or even archaic) language, which is presumably what you intend.

Comment: Thank! Also I'm sorry, but I still don't know if 'hold a claim to' is correct, it sounds better than 'have a claim to', but not sure if it's correct.

Comment: I would use an article: "**the** Tenji that was, died..."